# SQL - How to find missing activity days using start_date and end_date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a few fields in a database that look like this:

```
trip_id

start_date  
end_date

start_station_name  
end_station_name
```

I need to write a query that shows all the stations with no activity on a particular day in the year 2015. I wrote the following query but it's not giving the right output:

```
select
    start_station_name,
    extract(date from start_date) as dt,
    count(*)
from
    trips_table
where
    (
        start_date >= timestamp('2015-01-01')
        and
        start_date < timestamp('2016-01-01')
    )
group by
    start_station_name,
    dt 
order by
    count(*)
```

Can someone help come up with the right query? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about end_date?

Comment: And why the MySQL tag?

Comment: I took off the mysql tag. I need to write it in google-bigquery. The end_date works the same way as start_date, so if there's any activity on either then we won't count it for that day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

It assumes start_date and end_date are of DATE type
It also assumes that all days in between start_date and end_date are "dedicated" to station in start_station_name field, which most likely not what is expected but question is missing details here thus such an assumption

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH days AS (
  SELECT day
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')) AS day
),
stations AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT start_station_name AS station
  FROM `trips_table`
)
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM stations CROSS JOIN days) AS s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `trips_table`, 
           UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date)) AS day) AS a
ON s.day = a.day AND s.station = a.start_station_name
WHERE a.day IS NULL
```

You can test/play it with below simple/dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `trips_table` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS trip_id, DATE '2015-01-01' AS start_date, DATE '2015-12-01' AS end_date, '111' AS start_station_name UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2015-12-10', DATE '2015-12-31', '111'
),
days AS (
  SELECT day
  FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')) AS day
),
stations AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT start_station_name AS station
  FROM `trips_table`
)
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM stations CROSS JOIN days) AS s
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `trips_table`, 
           UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(start_date, end_date)) AS day) AS a
ON s.day = a.day AND s.station = a.start_station_name
WHERE a.day IS NULL
ORDER BY station, day
```

the output is like below

```sql
station day  
111     2015-12-02   
111     2015-12-03   
111     2015-12-04   
111     2015-12-05   
111     2015-12-06   
111     2015-12-07   
111     2015-12-08   
111     2015-12-09
```

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion for this purpose: try this SQL SERVER

```
WITH sample AS (
  SELECT CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATETIME) AS dt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, dt)
  FROM sample s
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, dt) < CAST('2016-01-01' AS DATETIME)
) 
SELECT * FROM sample
Where CAST(sample.dt as date) NOT IN (
  SELECT CAST(start_date as date) 
  FROM tablename 
  WHERE start_date >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
  AND start_date < '2016-01-01 00:00:00' 
) 
Option(maxrecursion 0)
```

If you want the station data with it then you can use left join as :

```
 WITH sample AS (
  SELECT CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATETIME) AS dt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, dt)
  FROM sample s
  WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, dt) < CAST('2016-01-01' AS DATETIME)
) 
SELECT * FROM sample
left join tablename 
on CAST(sample.dt as date)  = CAST(tablename.start_date as date) 
where sample.dt>= '2015-01-01 00:00:00' and sample.dt< '2016-01-01 00:00:00' ) 
Option(maxrecursion 0)
```

For mysql, see this fiddle. I think this would help you.... 
[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b1684/1)

Comment: Sorry that was my fault, I shouldn't have put mysql in the tag.